# How to gets ScrollBars in SVG for multiple content

Tags: svg

I want to have a container SVG which contain four SVG contents. Now these four SVG content has more content than can fit in the area allocated to them within the container SVG, hence I require that scrollbars appear automatically so that the full svg content can be seen by the user by scrolling.

I have tried establishing new viewports by adding the attributes width and height but scroll bars do not appear. I even tried using the overflow property with values of scroll and auto but still scrollbars do not appear.

What is the correct solution to this problem ?

Comment: You have gotten good answers for 6 questions, but have accepted no answers. You should strongly consider marking the answer that best answered your question (if any) as "accepted" by clicking the big checkmark. This helps the site, it helps other users with similar questions, it helps your reputation, and it helps other users not ignore you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment the answer is that you need to provide your own panning/scrolling functions, there's no way to get scrollbars inside of the svg apart from possibly wrapping it inside another html container via foreignObject (which would likely be suboptimal).

Here are some resources to get you started with custom svg scrollbars:

- http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/gui/scrollbar/
- http://www.treebuilder.de/default.asp?file=67211.xml
- http://www.dotuscomus.com/svg/lib/library.html

Comment: This is what I was fearing, too bad that such a basic thing needs to be coded by the developer