# dc.js - add scroll bar or zoom to bar chart - items not dates

Tags: dc.js

I have some barcharts, which all look great while there are only up to about 50 items to display, however the items bars are getting too small to click on when the number items get up towards 100.

I would like to fix the width of the items bars and then maybe scroll the bar chart if the number of items goes over 75, or would it be better to use some kind of zoom function?

I've looked at the Nasdaq 100 example but unsure how to apply this to items rather than dates? I'm struggling to find any examples to investigate. I saw this post but cannot comment [How to make graphs in dc.js scrollable within a fixed dimension div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124156/how-can-i-make-graphs-in-dc-js-scrollable-within-a-fixed-dimension-div)

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: As I commented in the other question, please try `mouseZoomable`. The zoom features need a little love, and there are some issues with ordinal domains, but it may just work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your bar chart:

```
.mouseZoomable(true)
```

The documentation for this can be found here: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-1.6.0.md#coordinate-grid-chart