# How to move the x-axis to the top for row chart using dc.js or d3.js

Tags: dc.js

My row chart is very long lengthwise. So scroll is necessary to look for the x-axis labels.

I wish to move it to the top in this simple example.

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/cust.html

```
spenderRowChart
.width(350).height(200)
.dimension(nameDim)
.group(spendPerName)
.elasticX(true);
```

Thanks!

Comment: It can probably be moved up but it wont be fixed even then. As you scroll down it will go out of view. You could try using custom svg scrollers as stated in this topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720627/how-to-gets-scrollbars-in-svg-for-multiple-content

Maybe some one can update if there has been any new development on it. Good luck

Comment: This is not directly supported by dc.js. You can move it to the top with a renderlet, and you can flip it using [d3.axis.orient](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#orient) but it will still mess up the vertical grid lines, because those are placed relative to the ticks in the axis.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will try it with a renderlet and customize it. If it doesn't work, I will try using scrollers!